# Getting scraped href linked with our website

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap thorough this anchor tag `<a href="/user/all?tag=114"> </a>`
But I am getting the result as `mywebsite.com/user/all?tag=114` any way to avoid it and only get what's on anchor tag no need of linking the href link with my website, Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to get the `href` attribute value:

- [`HTMLAnchorElement.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/href)
- [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector('a');
const {href} = anchor;
const hrefRaw = anchor.getAttribute('href');

console.log({href, hrefRaw});
```

```html
<a href="/user/all?tag=114">link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks getAttribute helped